# Minimum value in a quadratic function

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, maxima-minima

From an entrance exam:

> If the function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ has a minimum value in the set of real numbers, what holds true?
>
> 1. $a < 0$
> 2. $a = 0$
> 3. $a > 0$
> 4. None of the above.

The correct answer was option 3, but wouldn't $a=b=0$ work, thus making option 4 the correct one?

Comment: To be perfectly rigorous, I guess that you are right. Constant functions indeed "have a minimum value".

Comment: $a>0$ and $a=b=0$ both work. I don't know if the question excplicitly asked for a UNIQUE minimum value. Also, maybe the question was asking for a condition that only contrains the value of $a$, so that it holds true for any value of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I think this is probably an error in the question; that is, the test-maker was thinking of an upward-opening parabola, which is the graph of $f(x)$ over the reals when $f(x)$ has a unique minimum **point**, and neglected the fact that a constant function also has a minimum **value**. So technically option 4 is the correct answer. Exams do have wrong questions sometimes.

Comment: The title says "*quadratic function*" while the question says "*function*". That makes a big difference, because the function is not a quadratic when $a=b=0$.